# Mockito when clause with typed vararg parameter - Unit test using anyVararg

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am using Mockito & JUnit. I am trying to mock a method, which takes vararg parameters with fixed type.

Pseudo code of Method which I am trying to mock :

```
public class Alpha {
    public String test(String...args){return "abcd";}
}
```

Test code I would like to have :

```
Alpha alphaMock = Mockito.mock(Alpha.class);
when(alphaMock.test(anyVararg(String.class)).thenReturn("success");
```

But Mockito.anyVararg() doesn't take type argument. How can we handle this scenario ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`anyVararg` is a parameterized method. Try:

```
Alpha alphaMock = Mockito.mock(Alpha.class);
when(alphaMock.test(Matchers.<String> anyVararg())).thenReturn("success");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try casting the anyVarag() to String directly, eg:-

when(alphaMock.test((String)anyVararg()).thenReturn("success");

Comment: this solution works. Since the syntax was elegant using generics, I have accepted the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with array:

`any(String[].class)`

since that's what vararg essentially is

Comment: already tried this., it only works if the parameter is also String[]

Comment: this will compile but our expected mock behavior will not be available - In our example, "success" will not be returned., It will return null (default mock behavior). Because, matcher doesn't think it is equal.